# JS replace regular expression but use part of the expression in the output like a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

In making a simple bbcode parser, need to find within a string a substring like `[color=blue]` and replace it with something like `<span style="color:blue">`. I've been using regular expressions and javascript .replace() to do this. How can I use a regular expression to find what I need, but then also extract the color name to use in the span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```js
var input = "[color=blue]";
var output = input.replace(/\[color=([a-z]+)\]/ig, "<span style=\"color:$1\">");
console.log(output);
```

The pertinent bit is that `$1` which designates the first capture group.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    function my_func(whole_match, group1, group2) {
      return '<span style="' + group1 + ':' + group2 + '">';

    }

    var regex = /\[([^=]+)=([^\]]+)\]/;
    var str = 'hello [color=blue] world';
    var result = str.replace(regex, my_func);

  console.log(
      result
  );


});

--output:--
hello <span style="color:blue"> world
```

Answer (score 1):

For the **simple case**, you can use the `/\[color=([a-z]+)\]/g` regex:

```
var str = 'Hi there [color=blue] friend and [color=red] not friend';
str = str.replace(/\[color=([a-z]+)\]/g, '<span style="color:$1">');
console.log(str);
```

Output:

```xml
Hi there <span style="color:blue"> friend and <span style="color:red"> not friend
```

If you have **closing tags**, use `/\[color=([a-z]+)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/g`:

```
var s2 = 'Hi there [color=blue]friend[/color] and [color=red]not friend[/color]';
s2 = s2.replace(/\[color=([a-z]+)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/g, '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>');
console.log(s2);
```

Output:

```xml
Hi there <span style="color:blue">friend</span> and <span style="color:red">not friend</span>
```

If you have **nested tags**, you have to call `replace` twice:

```
var s4 = 'a[color=blue]b[color=red]c[/color]d[/color]e';
s4 = s4.replace(/\[color=([a-z]+)\]/g, '<span style="color:$1">');
s4 = s4.replace(/\[\/color\]/g, '</span>');
console.log(s4);
```

Output:

```
a<span style="color:blue">b<span style="color:red">c</span>d</span>e
```

[See testing fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SDG6v/1/).

<sub>Bear in mind regexes are not designed to deal with nesting. Because your case is simple, though, it works with two replaces - but may have some collateral effects, like creating a closing `</span>` to a `span` that was never opened (if the user types `[/color]` only). If you really need, we can create a regex that will deal with nesting, but only up to a certain level and at the price of really complicating the expression.</sub>